# VB.Net: Combining Stopwatch values

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, stopwatch

I currently have two stopwatches ( running in a VB 2010 program. What I would like to do is combine their values together and have their results outputted in a string formatted as 0:00:00.

I tried the Add method and the + method but this fails.

This is in short what I have:

```
Dim timer1 As New Stopwatch
Dim timer2 As New Stopwatch

[Assuming the timers were started separately]

Dim elapsed1 As TimeSpan = timer1.Elapsed
Dim elapsed2 As TimeSpan = timer2.Elapsed

elapsed1 += elapsed2
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this:

```
Dim elapsed3 As TimeSpan = elapsed1.Add(elapsed2)
```

or read from [MSDN TimeSpan.Add Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.add.aspx)